# Google Earth Network Link with Fusion Heat Map

Tags: dictionary, networking, hyperlink, heat

So I have created a heat map in Fusion Tables, obtained a API key and copied the code into the link in Google Earth Network Link add.  I did not get the resulting heat map to populate in Google Earth.  I've set the sharing to Public and Unlisted but neither bears any fruit.  Can anyone tell me what steps I am missing to get the heat map to populate in Google Earth?

Here is my obtained code (XXX'd out my API key)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"></meta>
<title>Copy of Heat Map - Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;libraries=visualization"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.location.protocol == "file:") {
    alert('This script only works when loaded from a web server,' +
        ' not from a file on your computer.');
  }
  function ftOnLoadClientApi() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('XxxXxxXxxxXx');
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=ftOnLoadClientApi">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;

  function loadApi() {
    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', initialize);
  }

  function initialize() {
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.070831120253633, -82.434892289917),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var query = 'select col2, col1 from 1-6pqmYvsmKGwt9IZcpIxFUmyYwmumoMAtMrE8pMe limit 1000';
    var request = gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sqlGet({ sql: query });
    request.execute(function(response) {
      onDataFetched(response);
    });
  }

  function onDataFetched(response) {
    if (response.error) {
      alert('Unable to fetch data. ' + response.error.message +
          ' (' + response.error.code + ')');
    } else {
      drawHeatmap(extractLocations(response.rows));
    }
  }

  function extractLocations(rows) {
    var locations = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
      var row = rows[i];
      if (row[0]) {
        var lat = row[0];
        var lng = row[1];
        if (lat && lng && !isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
          locations.push(latLng);
        }
      }
    }
    return locations;
  }

  function drawHeatmap(locations) {
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
       dissipating: true,
       gradient: [
         'rgba(102,255,0,0)', 
         'rgba(147,255,0,1)', 
         'rgba(193,255,0,1)', 
         'rgba(238,255,0,1)', 
         'rgba(244,227,0,1)', 
         'rgba(244,227,0,1)', 
         'rgba(249,198,0,1)', 
         'rgba(255,170,0,1)', 
         'rgba(255,113,0,1)', 
         'rgba(255,57,0,1)', 
         'rgba(255,0,0,1)'
       ],
       opacity: 0.49,
       radius: 20,
       data: locations
    });
    heatmap.setMap(map);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadApi);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```